# Add numbered bullets using Oracle LISTAGG function

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

Is it possible to add numbered bullets using Oracle's LISTAGG function?

i.e.:

I have a table:

```
PRODUCT_ID    PRODUCT_NAME
1001          Bananas
1002          Apples
1003          Pears
1004          Oranges
```

SQL statement:

```
SELECT LISTAGG('*' || product_name, CHR(13)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name) "Product_Listing"
FROM products;
```

`*` is a numbered bullet that should produce the ff:

```
1. Apples
2. Bananas
3. Oranges
4. Pears
```

Also, is it possible to use letters instead of numbers?

Comment: There is no need of `LISTAGG` here. You just need to assign row number to each row and concatenate it with other column. Also, rememebr, `LISTAGG` has SQL limit of **4000 characters/bytes**.

Comment: I need to produce one row only. I will use this as data to a report.

Comment: `chr(13)` is carriage return.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Product_Listing_1` gives you number bullets, the `Product_Listing_2` gives you letter bullets.

```
with products as (
    select 1001 as product_id, 'Bananas' as product_name from dual
    union all
    select 1002 as product_id, 'Apples' as product_name from dual
    union all
    select 1003 as product_id, 'Pears' as product_name from dual
    union all
    select 1004 as product_id, 'Oranges' as product_name from dual
),
make_bullets$ as (
    select X.*,
        row_number() over (partition by null order by product_name) as the_number_bullet,
        chr(ascii('a') - 1 + row_number() over (partition by null order by product_name)) as the_letter_bullet
    from products X
)
select
    listagg(the_number_bullet||'. '||product_name, chr(13)) within group (order by product_name) as "Product_Listing_1",
    listagg(the_letter_bullet||'. '||product_name, chr(13)) within group (order by product_name) as "Product_Listing_2"
from make_bullets$
;
```

Result:

```
Product_Listing_1    Product_Listing_2
-----------------    -----------------
1. Apples            a. Apples
2. Bananas           b. Bananas
3. Oranges           c. Oranges
4. Pears             d. Pears
```

Comment: Just nit picking... `PARTITION BY NULL` is pointless use. http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/189130/

Comment: @LalitKumarB, I know. Yet, I always use it to underline the "no partitioning" of the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number() in subquery to generate number

```
with products as
(
select 1001 as product_id,  'Bananas' as product_name from dual union all
select 1002 as product_id,  'Apples' as product_name from dual union all
select 1003 as product_id,  'Pears' as product_name from dual union all
select 1004 as product_id,  'Oranges' as product_name from dual
)
SELECT LISTAGG(rn||'. '|| product_name, CHR(13)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name) "Product_Listing" 
FROM
   (SELECT product_id, product_name, row_number() over (order by product_name) as rn
      FROM products)
```

or rownum

```
SELECT LISTAGG(rownum||'. '|| product_name, CHR(13)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name) "Product_Listing" 
FROM
   (SELECT product_id, product_name
      FROM products
     ORDER BY product_name)
```

Comment: `LISTAGG` with `chr(13)` as delimiter makes no sense to me.

Comment: Strange, coz for me its work fine. http://i.stack.imgur.com/6uPbX.png (SQL Developer 4). Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I am not saying it won't work. I am just saying that LISTAGG is just unnecessary here. First you are forcing string aggregation, and then using chr(13) as delimiter. Which is contradictory. All you need is to assign a row number to each row. Also, remember, `LISTAGG` has SQL limit of **4000 characters**.

Comment: I think if OP use LISTAGG this means that he needs one string value instead numerated rows (it can be used in reports for example).  Actually, it is important to know restrictions of listagg, but if Business logic demands one string value, you need to return it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use `LISTAGG` at all. LISTAGG is for string aggregation, and you do not need aggregation at all.

You could use **ROW_NUMBER()** analytic function and **concatenation operator** `||` to get your desired output.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1001 PRODUCT_ID, 'Bananas' PRODUCT_NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1002, 'Apples' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1003, 'Pears' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1004, 'Oranges' FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY product_name)||'. '||product_name my_bullet_list
  8  FROM DATA;

MY_BULLET_LIST
-------------------------------------------------
1. Apples
2. Bananas
3. Oranges
4. Pears
```

If you are not concerned about the ordering of the rows, you could simply use **ROWNUM** pseudo column.

Comment: I need to produce one row only. I will use this as data to a report.